# Grails: Detached Criteria for multiple nested relationships

Tags: sorting, grails, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

I am trying to sort my data by a layer 3 relationship but I can't see to get it to work.  I have successfully use aliases to query for level 2 relationships.  This is how I have my query setup

```
def query = Application.where {}

query.createAlias("applicationDegrees", "appDegrees");
query.createAlias("applicationDegrees.degree", "degree");
query.createAlias("applicationDegrees.applicationDegreeMajors", "appMajors");
query.createAlias("applicationDegrees.applicationDegreeMajors.major", "major");


return query.list([sort: "degree.code", order: "desc"]); //WORKS
return query.list([sort: "major.code", order: "desc"]);  //DOES NOT WORK
```

As you can see from my example code above, I can sort by appDegrees and degree.  When I try to take it a step further and sort based off appMajors or major which are relationships of appDegrees it does not sort properly.  No sort is applied at all but no error messages are throw either.

This is my data model

```
class Application {
    Set<ApplicationDegree> applicationDegrees = []

    static hasMany = [applicationDegrees: ApplicationDegree]
}

class ApplicationDegree {
    Application app
    Degree degree
    Set applicationDegreeMajors = []

    static hasMany = [applicationDegreeMajors: ApplicationDegreeMajor]
    static belongsTo = [Application, Degree]
}

class ApplicationDegreeMajor {
    ApplicationDegree applicationDegree
    Major major

    static belongsTo = [ApplicationDegree, Major]
}
```

How do I create my aliases so that I can sort by Major?

Grails 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the answer (and a workaround) may be found here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=947709

It seems that nested aliases are not supported so I suggest to replace their creation like that:

```
query.createAlias("applicationDegrees", "appDegrees");
query.createAlias("appDegrees.degree", "degree");
query.createAlias("appDegrees.applicationDegreeMajors", "appMajors");
query.createAlias("appMajors.major", "major");
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, trying to create an alias as your specified throws an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument [appMajors.major] is not an association`

Comment: Okay, I've edited the answer and provided a wider example as per info taken from the mentioned link. Please verify.